# How to setup laravel with npm using docker-compose?

Tags: laravel, docker, npm

I have the next docker-compose.yml file

```
version: '2'
services:
  # The Application
  app:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: app.dockerfile
    working_dir: /var/www/html
    volumes:
      - ./giftmeabetterplanet:/var/www/html
    environment:
      - "DB_PORT=3306"
      - "DB_HOST=database"

  # The Web Server
  web:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: web.dockerfile
    working_dir: /var/www/html
    links:
      - database:mysql
    volumes_from:
      - app
    ports:
      - 81:80
    environment:
      - "WEB_DOCUMENT_ROOT=/var/www/html/public"
  # The Database
  database:
    image: mysql:5.6
    volumes:
      - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      - "MYSQL_DATABASE=homestead"
      - "MYSQL_USER=homestead"
      - "MYSQL_PASSWORD=secret"
      - "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=secret"
    ports:
        - "3306"

volumes:
  dbdata:
```

I need to make NPM (node package manager) accessible somehow to build my JS and CSS files in 'web' container.

app.dockerfile

```
FROM php:7.0.4

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libmcrypt-dev \
    mysql-client libmagickwand-dev --no-install-recommends \
    && pecl install imagick \
    && docker-php-ext-enable imagick \
    && docker-php-ext-install mcrypt pdo_mysql
```

web.dockerfile

```
FROM webdevops/php-apache-dev:ubuntu-16.04
```

I've tried the next way by extending web.dockerfile

```
FROM orlandohohmeier/local-npm
FROM webdevops/php-apache-dev:ubuntu-16.04
```

But npm is not accessible from the command line in 'web' container. Maybe i don't understand some concepts but i just want to compile my stiles, javascript files and copy fonts from node-modules.

Best regards. Ivan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding this to your web.dockerfile.

```
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs npm
```

And then build your containers and try running node or npm within the web container

```
docker-compose run web bash
```

Comment: Sorry. Doesn't work. I don't have this repos in my Docerfile's

Comment: Can you share your dockerfile?

Answer (score 5):

For PHP7.2 this is what I have in my php.dockerfile

`RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | bash - 
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs`

Answer (score 5):

Add to the **docker-compose** file

```
npm:  
  image: node:14
  working_dir: /var/www/my_shiny_project
  entrypoint: ["npm"]
  volumes: 
    - "./www/:/var/www/my_shiny_project"
```

Usage:

```
docker-compose run --rm npm install
```

Don't forget to check the paths in both **working_dir** and **volumes**

Answer (score 2):

Follow this tutorial: https://medium.com/@wiwatSrt/laravel-development-environment-in-docker-containers-7b173f62f372

When docker-compose is set up, run command:

```
docker-compose run --rm nodejs npm install
```